# Acelerar importe de PhpExcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Buen dia,
Cuando hago el importe de archivos de hasta mil registros no se demora, pero cuando voy aumentando la cantidad de registros se demora mucho.
Mi pregunta es si alguien sabe como acelerar el importe de phpexcel.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que phpexcel tiene ese problema común (también para exportar demasiados registros). Prueba spout. Es más ligero:

-Doc ..: http://opensource.box.com/spout/

-Repo .: https://github.com/box/spout

Comment: Gracias por tu comentaria lo voy a analizar, pero seguro que no hay manera de acelerarlo?

Comment: Probablemente si, pero probablemente tengas que configurar cosas extras y tal vez meterle mano a la biblioteca, lo cual ya no sería tan recomendable. Además, si necesitaras exportar grandes volúmenes de tu información, con spout sería más rápido.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias voy a tomar tu comentario, pero sabes donde puedo ver tutoriales o cuales me aconsejas.

Comment: ¿Tutoriales sobre qué compañero @Kygo?

Comment: De spout o es muy similar a phpexcel?

Comment: Spout y PHPExcel hacen prácticamente el mismo trabajo (trabajar con hojas de excel), pero spout es más rápido para importar/exportar grandes volúmenes de datos sin necesidad de configuraciones extras forzosas. con PHPExcel le das presentación a tus hojas de cálculo al exportar y demás. Checa el primer enlace, ahí te viene la documentación. No es difícil. En caso que tengas el zip o lo tengas descargado con composer me parece que en el archivo README vienen ejemplos.

Comment: Ok Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.